# What is the probability that a random person selected is diseased, given a positive detection?

Tags: probability

There is a method to detect certain disease with 99% sensitivity and 90% specificity. And also it is known that 5% of the population has this disease.

What is the probability a random person selected from the population actually has this disease given that the method detects so?

Comment: See [Bayes theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem#Extended_form).

Comment: Your header is Bayesian probability question, so you must know Bayes' rule, what exactly is your specific difficulty ?

Comment: @trueblueanil: I am not sure how to understand the reasoning behind sensitivity and specificity in this case. So can anyone please provide a complete solution?

Comment: $\dfrac{\Pr(\text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{well})} \cdot \dfrac{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{well})} = \dfrac{\Pr(\text{ill} \mid \text{positive})}{\Pr(\text{well}\mid\text{positive})}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensitivity is the probability that someone that has the disease tests positive for it, and specificity is the probability that someone who does not have the disease tests negative.  See [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bayes-theorem/) for a more detailed explanation. So if we let $X$ represent a positive test and $D$ represent the patient having the disease then $P(X|D)=0.99$ and $P(X|\neg D)=0.1$.  Apply Bayes rule and take two asprin if symptoms persist.

Answer (score 0):

The binary nature of the "parameter space" $\{\text{ill},\text{well}\}$ makes this simple formuation possible:

$$\frac{\Pr(\text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{well})} \cdot \frac{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{well})} = \frac{\Pr(\text{ill} \mid \text{positive})}{\Pr(\text{well}\mid\text{positive})}.$$

The numerator and denominator of the first fraction above are "prior probabilities"; those of the last are "posterior probabilities".

One may write it thus:
$$
\operatorname{logit} \Pr(\text{ill}) + \log\frac{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{well})} = \operatorname{logit} \Pr(\text{ill} \mid \text{positive}).
$$

where
$$
\operatorname{logit} p = \log \frac{p}{1-p}.
$$
(Google the word "logit" and you'll see it.)

So $\dfrac{\Pr(\text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{well})}= \dfrac{5}{95}=\dfrac{1}{19}$ and $\dfrac{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{ill})}{\Pr(\text{positive} \mid \text{well})} = \dfrac{99}{10}$.  Plug in the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

deinst has explained sensitivity & specificity.

Here's a less technical  way of solving.

P[true positive] = 99% of 5% = 4.95%

P[false positive] = 10% of 95% = 9.5%

P[true positive | positive] = 4.95/(4.95+9.5)